# How to add vertical lines in Kibana?

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I am working with Kibana 5.4.3 and I am building a distribution chart (as indicated in the graph below in green). This looks like a gaussian distribution and for that reason i would like two add two vertical red lines to indicate the standar deviation. Do you know how I can realize this ?

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the functionality of the existing visualization then Kibana Plugin development is the route you can choose. Kibana plugin development related info is available at - [Kibana Plugin development](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/plugin-development.html).